# querying mongodb documents based on expiry field

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with a field of `"expiryTime"`. Now, I want to alert users when their subscription is about to expire. I want to do it when they have 1 day/1 week/1 month left to their expiration, but I don't know how to retrieve these documents. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You could `"$match"` documents where `"$dateDiff"` between `"$$NOW"` and `"$expiryTime"` is greater than whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

A bit difficult to provide a solution without any sample data. Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $gt: [
          "$expireTime",
          { $dateAdd: { startDate: "$$NOW", unit: "day",  amount: 1 } }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```